# Play Framework: How to get the absolute path of an asset

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

My Play application automatically generates some HTML emails, which of course reference some images on the server. Since HTML emails require full URLs to get the images on the client side, I've defined the base URL in my `application.conf` and then build the full path in my view template. That said, is there a way to get the complete URL of the `public/images` directory so that I no longer need an additional configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you can get the full URL on an asset using reverse routing:

```
routes.Assets.at("images/anImage.png").absoluteURL()
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch ;-) It works... but the correct syntax is routes.assets.at("images/anImage.png").absoluteURL().

Comment: In Play 2.x, `routes.assets` should be `routes.Assets`.

Comment: This also works (just did this under Play 2.4.x) for other site urls like `routes.controller.Application.terms().absoluteURL()` and `routes.controller.Application.privacy().absoluteURL()` for example. (useful for footers in the email...)