# Play framework - how to write to public assets

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Trying to process uploaded images and then display the result. Was following: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-fileupload-example

Relevant snippet:

```
private def handleFilePartAsFile: FilePartHandler[File] = {
  case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
    val path: Path = Files.createTempFile("multipartBody", "tempFile")
    val fileSink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(path)
    val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, IOResult] = Accumulator(fileSink)
    accumulator.map {
      case IOResult(count, status) =>
        logger.info(s"count = $count, status = $status")
        FilePart(partName, filename, contentType, path.toFile)
    }
}
```

How can I get the absolute path of the `/public/images` asset folder, to write the image to, instead of using `Files.createTempFile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Framework: How to get the absolute path of an asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840043/play-framework-how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-an-asset)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Linked issue is regarding getting the absolute path of an existing asset, as opposed to the absolute path of the asset directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you will use Play 2.6 like in the project from the link you mentioned. 
In that case you can construct path to file in /public/images folder from 4 paths:

1. absolute path of the deployed Play! application
2. base (relative) path to assets folder
3. /images
4. file name

In Scala:

```
val path = env.rootPath + af.assetsBasePath + "/images/" + filename
```

For 1st and 2nd parts you need to auto-inject Environment and AssetsFinder objects like:

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() (cc:MessagesControllerComponents, 
    af: AssetsFinder, env: Environment)
(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
...
```